# Browser version floor for custom HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, html

Which browsers (and versions) do not support custom attributes?

I want to add some custom attributes to my tags and I would like to know which browsers will not handle this properly.

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv" mycustomattribute="I've got one.">Test</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
alert(document.getElementById("mydiv").getAttribute("mycustomattribute"));
```

Comment: As far as I know they all support it, but instead of doing that you should use the HTML5 "data-" attribute pattern.  Any attribute whose name starts with "data-" is explicitly allowed by the HTML5 spec.

Comment: I'm not sure on a complete list, but custom attributes worked as far back as Netscape 3 and IE 4.

Comment: @EBarr Ktash's answer has a pretty good list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, use the [`data-*` for custom attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). That will be HTML5 compatible. Secondly, [all browsers currently support it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset) while using `getAttribute()`

Answer (score 1):

If you add custom attributes, it will make your page invalid (but page will be rendered just fine).

There is a way of creating custom attributes in [HTML5,](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml) though.